# How to put a custom type in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm using Hibernate, JPA and Spring Boot.

I would like to persist a custom Object of type "Version". "Version" is an Object with complex processing but it corresponds in the table to a simple VARCHAR field. I'm able to construct Version from String and construct String from Version object.

```
class MyEntity {

    @Column("version_sw")
    private Version version; <-- I would like to persist version as a String
}
```

I'm looking at different way to create hibernate type :

- UserType : Seems overkill for me because my object map to only one Column in database.
- BasicType (with AbstractTypeDescriptor) : Seems good but not sure if it's the right way to do that
- CompositeUserType : Seems not good for my needs

Is there a missing and simple way in order to do that ?

Thanks !!

Comment: I don't know if it's "best practice" approach but you can set your version field as String and map it to database. Then go to Version class and create two methods "fromString" and "toString". And go back to your MyEntity class and write getters,setters to version field. For setter method use Version.fromString and for getter method user Version.toString

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understend you just need to convert you object to strings and save on data base, to do that you can use JPA attribute converter, so you can convert your complex object to string, some kind of json for exemple and save it on table. And to use on your system you must convert the string to one object.
Try this: https://thoughts-on-java.org/jpa-21-how-to-implement-type-converter/